# BST(Binary Search Tree) Testdome in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, namedtuple

I need solution about the problem which is posted in test-dome.

Here is Problem

Binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where the value of each node is larger or equal to the values in all the nodes in that node's left subtree and is smaller than the values in all the nodes in that node's right subtree.

Write a function that, efficiently with respect to time used, checks if a given binary search tree contains a given value.

For example, for the following tree:

n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null)
n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right: n3)
n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null)
Call to contains(n2, 3) should return True since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

And Following is my answer. 
I'm programming  python.

```
import collections
Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['left', 'right', 'value'])

def contains(root, value):
    if value == root.value:
        return True
    elif value > root.value:
        if root.right != None:
            return contains(root.right, value)
    elif value < root.value:
        if root.left != None:
            return contains(root.right, value)


n1 = Node(value=1, left=None, right=None)
n3 = Node(value=3, left=None, right=None)
n2 = Node(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)

print(contains(n2, 2))
```

Now, I passed 33.3%, Please help me to pass 100%

Comment: That's cheating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check first if root is `None`, then return `False`, you don't need to check if `root.left is None` or `root.right is None`

Then like the other answer mentioned, your code always looks to right.

If the value you are looking for is less than root's value go to left.

Also you don't need `elif` because you are returning from the `if`

With those changes:

```
def contains(root, value):
    if root is None:
        return False
    if value == root.value:
        return True
    if value > root.value:
        return contains(root.right, value)
    if value < root.value:
        return contains(root.left, value)
```

Comment: perfect!! I got two points 1. what's long in my logic 2. syntax enhancement! (if)

Answer (score 1):

point 1: you are going right sub-tree always. whether the root value is lower or higher than the key.

point 2: you should go left when the root value is higher than the key.

point 3: you should go right  when the root value is lower than the key.

do the following changes in your code:

```
if value == root.value:
    return True
elif root.value > value:
    if root.left != None:
        return contains(root.left, value) #going left
elif root.value < value:
    if root.right != None:
         return contains(root.right, value) #going right
```